# What is the correct method to set up a remote SSH connection on cellular to a Raspberry Pi over AWS?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssh, amazon-web-services

Sorry in advance if the following is incorrectly assumed, but I have a device that won't be able to connect to a wifi network, and instead will need to utilise a mobile network to do so. The idea is:

[Comms layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDCer.png)

I was reading through the [AWS Secure Tunneling Demo](https://github.com/aws-samples/iot-secure-tunneling-demo) which specifies to use a Cloud9 instance, but this instance type seems to just be for testing purposes.

There is also this on how to [open a tunnel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/tunneling-tutorial-quick-setup.html) using the AWS IoT interface, but I feel like there are some bits of information I am missing. Both methods seem to use MQTT which is expected.

This is the first time I am looking at remote ssh over a cellular network, so I'm not sure if I am searching for the incorrect phrase or something, but if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful.

**Edits**

Just some further thoughts:

- The pi essentially acts as a server, so it will always need  to be listening for a connection - so this would make it a pub/sub client